# Sharepoint backup methods?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, backup

I currently do indiidual site collection (6) backups on my sharepoint site.

What are some of the best autmoized methods to backup a sharepoint site (site collections and sites with content)?
For some reason everytime I try to do a web app backup it fails.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here are a few methods that you could use to backup!

this one is using powershell

http://sharepointpolice.com/blog/2010/12/07/automated-powershell-script-to-backup-sharepoint-farm-or-site-collection-with-email-notification/

do it using sharepoints own tools!

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markarend/archive/2010/05/27/backup-restore-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx

tech from microsoft using Owsadm.exe (command line)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768008.aspx

also have a look at this automated backup someone created

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/da/sharepoint2010setup/thread/15d5a8ae-c112-4841-a105-8836b2de1a7e

Comment: no probs glad to help :)